# Specifying User while importing using hotfolder in Hybris

Tags: spring, sap-commerce-cloud, hotfolder, impex

I want to add categories to a catalog using hotfolder functionality of Hybris.

But while adding category using hotfolder at that time I am facing a issue for Interceptor written for checking current user. As hotfolder doesn't find any particular user that's why it shows me InterceptorException.

Can anybody knows how to execute this one with admin rights or anything where I can specify the user details for this execution.

Thanks in Advance.

P.S: Cannot paste code or anything else as working in security environment.

Comment: do you need usergroup to import category via hot-folder

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of options. You can try to enable legacy mode on the import or you can try to set up a context where there is a current user.

What is your interceptor trying to achieve? Your solution depends on that really.

Comment: My interceptor is getting usergroup of user through which the impex or anything else is fired. If that  user doesn`t have usergroup then error occurs. Also please tell me how to enable legacy mode while using hotfolder functionality. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

For who still need this, here you have an exemple:

```
<bean id="batchB2BCustomerConverter" class="de.hybris.platform.acceleratorservices.dataimport.batch.converter.impl.DefaultImpexConverter">
    <property name="header">
        <value># Insert b2bCustomer
            INSERT_UPDATE B2BCustomer[disable.interceptor.beans='B2BCustomerActivationInterceptor,B2BCustomerModelValidateInterceptor'] ; uid[unique=true]; email; name; title(code); groups(uid); sessionCurrency(isocode)[default='EUR']; sessionLanguage(isocode)[default='de'];active[default='true']
        </value>
    </property>
    <property name="impexRow">
        <value>;{+0};{+1};{+2};{3};{+4};{5};{6};{7}</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```